# Error Not assignable to the type Interface

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am building an angular 4 application. I have created an interface and returning a service method that is of type interface. I am getting an error is not assignable to the type IMovie[] while building the app using the ng build command on the command prompt.

Please see the screenshot below for more info

[image]

MovieComponent

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {MRDBCommonService} from '../shared/services/mrdb.common.service';
import {IMovie} from './movie.interface';
const URL_MOVIE = '/api/movie';

@Injectable()
export class MovieService 
{

constructor(private _mrdbCommonService: MRDBCommonService){}

    getMovies() : IMovie[] {
        return[
         {
            "movieId" : 1,
            "name" : "Titanic",
            "actor" : "Test1",
            "director" : "Test2",
            "movieLength" : 2 
         },
         {
            "movieId" : 2,
            "name" : "Top Gun",
            "actor" : "Test3",
            "director" : "Test4",
            "movieLength" : 2  
         },
         {
            "movieId" : 3,
            "name" : "Moloun Rouge",
            "actor" : "Test5",
            "director" : "Test5",
            "movieLength" : 2  
         }
        ];
    }

    createMovie(){

    }

    deleteMovie(){

    }

}
```

Movie interface

```
export interface IMovie{

    movieId : number;
    name : string;
    actor : string;
    director : string;
    movieLength : number;  
}
```

Comment: FYI, the Angular Style Guide suggests using classes instead of interfaces, and not to use I as a prefix either: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#interfaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes characters `"` around the property **keys** and try running `ng build` again and see if the error goes away. Interfaces are perfectly fine to use a long as the object structure matches the interface definition.

**UPDATE:** Be sure to remove any extra whitespace characters from the interface property keys otherwise the compiler may not recognize the property names cause build errors.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MRDBCommonService } from '../shared/services/mrdb.common.service';
import { IMovie } from './movie.interface';
const URL_MOVIE = '/api/movie';

@Injectable()
export class MovieService {

    constructor(private _mrdbCommonService: MRDBCommonService) { }

    getMovies(): IMovie[] {
        return [
            {
                movieId: 1,
                name: "Titanic",
                actor: "Test1",
                director: "Test2",
                movieLength: 2
            },
            {
                movieId: 2,
                name: "Top Gun",
                actor: "Test3",
                director: "Test4",
                movieLength: 2
            },
            {
                movieId: 3,
                name: "Moloun Rouge",
                actor: "Test5",
                director: "Test5",
                movieLength: 2
            }
        ];
    }

}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: In interface definition you provided, was it SO that added spaces after each key name and before the colon

Comment: Thanks Alex. I removed the spaces and it built correctly